# Can I use two datasource for Activiti in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

Now I have two database called db1 and db2,which both have the save process flow diagram.I want to execute the activiti process according according the parameter.
For example,if I pass the para which value is 1,I want to execute the activiti process using db1.if I pass the para which value is 2,I want to execute the activiti process using db2.Can I use two datasource for Activiti in a Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 2):

That can be technically achieved, but why? If I were you i would try to separate the each application to work against a different data source as much as I can. If you are aiming for a multi tenant use case i would recommend to just have different instances for each tenant.

Comment: Inorder to database partition,I have to store different data to different database.

Comment: Yeah so you can have two microservices in complete isolation and a router/gateway in front of them

Comment: And then use headers or any other technique to route between the two

Comment: Now I use one program to deal the parameter.So I have to decide which db1 should I to store data. I know spring boot can use dynamicDataSource.But activiti seem can not switch the db.

Comment: Which version of activiti are you using?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if these are two different environments that are mutually exclusive you should consider reading more about [Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

If the case is that you load the two beans and need to call one database to handle one job and another database to handle another part of the job you can create two domains and two repositories then configure two data sources and specify for which packages will the data source be executed based on the parameter as in [this example](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7)